# Transient fields reset after filter search

Tags: cuba-platform

I'm setting a transient attribute in the screen controller using a service to retrieve the information I need (which is a list of instances that need the attribute to be set). **The problem is that after using a filter, the transient attribute reset.** Is it expected? Is there a listener to be used after a filter is applied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is such listener:

```
@Inject
private Filter filter;

@Override
public void init(Map<String, Object> params) {
    filter.setAfterFilterAppliedHandler(() -> {

    });
}
```